# Using SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to use the example code from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html but the line

```
 System.out.println(sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation.class).toString(SemanticGraph.OutputFormat.LIST));
```

gives the error

> SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation cannot be
>   resolved to a type

even though I imported edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.
Eclipse suggests following quick fixes:

> Change to "AlternativeDependenciesAnnotation"
>   (edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations;)
>
> Change to "BasicDependenciesAnnotation"
>   (edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations;)

Applying the first fix leads to an java.lang.NullPointerException while the second fix gives following, rather unsatisfying results for the first sentence:

> Loading clause searcher from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz...1.0    Obama   be
>   bear in   Hawaii

The import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation; cannot be resolved and the import import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations; does not help either.

I imported the JARs

- joda-time
- stanford-corenlp-3.6.0
- stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models
- ejml-0.23
- jollyday
- xom
- slf4j
- slf4j-simple

I use CoreNLP 3.6.0. . I checked the SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.java in edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph and it contains the EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation.class . How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the example code was written for the latest version of OpenIE, which is so far only on GitHub. The easiest way of getting this to run would probably be to clone the [repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) and compile CoreNLP yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `stanford-corenlp-3.9.2` `jar`. This worked for me.